# Connecting springDataMongo app to Cosmos Db instead of MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have an existing java springboot application that uses springDataMongo api to connect to an underlying Mongodb instance.

I need to use the existing springDataMongo api classes but instead of Mongodb, I need to connect Cosmos Db.

I have looked it up on documentation for azure Cosmos db api for Mongodb but didn't get hold of what I am trying to do.

Can someone let me know if what I am doing is possible and if yes, point me to a relevant documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to connect to Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API using springDataMongo.

What you need to do is copy the Cosmos DB connection string from the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com) and then put it into `spring.data.mongodb.uri` in `application.properties` file of your spring boot project.

[image]

***application.properties***

```
#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://[username]:[passowrd]@[cosmosdbName].documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true
spring.data.mongodb.database=[dababaseName]
```

After that done, you can check this guide out: [Accessing Data with MongoDB](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I just need to change the connection properties switching from mongodb to cosmosdb and rest of the spring data mongo code in springboot app should work as is ?